# Twitter API 1.1 get json from PHP for use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, twitter

Essentially what I'm doing is trying to pull in Twitter data for use in Javascript app. I have a php file which is calling the API and retrieving JSON data, but I can't seem to access this data within my javascript file.

I'm trying to use this method.

```
$.getJSON("tweets_JSON.php?count=1&callback=listTweets");
```

Then to test it I'm using...

```
console.log(listTweets[0].id_str);
```

This returns a message that listTweets isn't defined. I've tried removing the callback form the url and declaring it as

```
var listTweets = $.getJSON("tweets_JSON.php?count=1&callback=listTweets");
```

This seems to access the first object in the array, but then I get an error saying the object property I'm looking for (`.id_str`) can't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you add a `callback` parameter, jQuery expects there to be an actual function with that name that is called

```
$.getJSON("tweets_JSON.php?count=1&callback=listTweets");

function listTweets(json) {

    console.log(json)

    // called when ajax call is completed
}
```

If you don't want that, and you're doing a call to your own server, just rename the GET parameter

```
$.getJSON("tweets_JSON.php?count=1&cbk=listTweets").done(function(json) {

    console.log(json)

    // called when ajax call is completed
});
```

Also, `console.log(listTweets[0].id_str);` does nothing, `listTweets` would be the name of a function, not some variable you can access later ?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. Your first method seems to work (at least it doesn't kick an error). I guess my follow up question would be how would you go about accessing the object properties like id_str?

Sorry if that's a stupidly basic question. I'm new to programming.

Comment: You would do that inside the function, `json` would be the returned data, and you can see it by logging it to the console, as in `console.log(json)`

Comment: Hmm, so it should look something like...

`$.getJSON("tweets_JSON.php?count=1&callback=listTweets");

function listTweets(json) {
    console.log(json);
};

listTweets();`

This is returning undefined?

Comment: Why not just remove the `callback` parameter if you're not going to use a callback function, just rename it to something else and use the second code snippet above

Comment: Because that would work, and I wouldn't be able to annoy benevolent strangers on the internet any longer. : ) 

I see the data now. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. Very much appreciated.